# To refresh the link published through Tableau public as data get updated in SQL server

Tags: tableau-api

I have made Tableau dashboard in Tableau Desktop & published it in Tableau public. Extract is used to data refresh, but when I refresh the data, the graph in the tableau Desktop get updated, but the published link does not. 
I am having only Tableau Desktop & Tableau public (does not have Tableau online, Tableau server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tableau Public doesn't connect to your SQL Server. The only way to update Tableau Public dashboards is to republish the entire workbook to Tableau Public after refreshing in Tableau Desktop.

Comment: But what about Tableau Desktop ?

Comment: Tableau Desktop can connect to your SQL Server. You would update your dashboard in Tableau Desktop - manually refreshing the extract (I think you would need to have an extract when publishing to Tableau Public). Once the extract is refreshed you would republish to Tableau Public.